# SQL Server Mirror failover on failing storage

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring, failover

Recently we had an issue with a sql server 2008 r2 HA mirror. I have tried to reproduce this in a lab environment and i came to the conclusion that i am missing something OR something is not possible.

I am using 2 sql server 2008 r2 servers. Both the servers have a iscsi storage connection to a storage server. Mirroring is done with a witness server in HS mode.
i have followed a blog post by Glenn Berry about how to create a group failover, he told me on twitter it would also be usable in case of failing storage. However, somewhere i can't really get things to work.

What am i doing. I have a sql-01 as princiapl and a sql-02 as mirror. 2 databases running in HA mirror mode. I have a failover script running on WMI 7 and 8. When i go to my storage server to disable the storage of sql-01 i would suspect that eventually i get a failover to sql-02. but it doesn't...

Anyone can give me some hints on this?

Edit : Failover with a shutdown-ed storage for sql-01 looks working, because of a tempdb that is getting corrupt which needs recovery (according to logs). Therefor the instance has to shutdown (also in the logs), so probably that is my reason i can failover from sql-01 to sql-02, by accident and apparently not by design.

Comment: Do you have a witness server? And are you running in High-Safety mode? Both are required for automatic failover ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189590(v=sql.105).aspx )

Comment: Yes, didn't told it in my question, will update it.

Comment: Can you failover manually? When you disable the storage of sql-01 are the databases 'failing' and are you seeing anything in the SQL logs?

Comment: Yeah, manually failovering works. That is also exactly what i want to do in this particulair case, but with the use of a WMI Alert / SQL Agent job. The errors i see are only related to not having storage ("The operating system returned error 21(The device is not ready.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x00000000130000 in file 'e:\MSSQL\Data\MirrorTest1.mdf'"). But that is when i try to query a certain table on that database on the server where the storage is down.

Comment: Is this the blog you're following? - http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/sql-server-database-mirroring-tips-and-tricks-part-3/ - I'm wondering if it's because all the DBs are on the same 'failed' drive so the ALTER DATABASE in the sp is failing?

Comment: Yes, following that blogpost. All the DB's are on the same drive. Strange, failover from sql-01 to sql-02 works when i disable the storage for sql-01, but back from sql-02 to sql-01 isn't working now. I really don't understand why. Also, this failover will be done after 30 seconds or something round that...

Comment: @Stuart your answer can be somewhat of a solution for my problem. Using mulitple storage devices per instance, where each database will have it;s own storage subsystem. Bit expensive though....

Comment: Is the corrupt tempdb on SQL-01 or SQL-02?

Comment: The corrupt database was on SQL-01, that's why the failover was initiated. The tempdb on SQL-02 doesn't seem to get corrupted thought when i disable the storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to move my part into an Answer.
It would appear the "problem" is that the script in the blog ( http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/sql-server-database-mirroring-tips-and-tricks-part-3/ ) is using an `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET PARTNER FAILOVER;` to failover the rest of the 'failover' group.

As all the dbs were on the same disk, this fails as SQL SERVER can't run the `ALTER DATABASE` command if it can't get in to the database. So moving the databases onto seperate disks fixes that.

But that sort of makes sense. If all the databases are on the same disk then they should failover automatically as a 'group' as they all need to be fail overed. The referenced script would make sense if you did have databases on seperate disks that needed to failover together if just one of the disks failed.

Comment: Makes sense! However, getting all databases on separate storage isn't a solution for me in this case, since the problem originally was on a system with 2 storage subsystems, one for log and one for data. I will put this in my report for this customer though!

Comment: Apparently this is the only way :)

Comment: For reference, i managed to get it to work by using 1 database with different files. On each disk i made a file and i periodically insert/truncate stuff in/from it. Don't know for sure if i can manage to get it to work without this inserting/truncating, but with i can failover much faster (no insert = failover in my case)